# Playframework 2.6.x FormUrlEncoded return null value in post action

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I tried to extract some manytomany values with 
request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("RolesItems");

But it seems to return a value here :

```
//DELETE Roles from Sysuser

public Result DeleteRoles(Long id) 
{
  String[] postAction = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("RolesItems");  
  Logger.info("Post Action is not null : "+postAction);
```

However, in the update method, the post action seems to be NULL and i don't know why ?

```
public CompletionStage<Result> update(Long id) throws PersistenceException {

String[] postAction = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("RolesItems");               
Logger.info("Post Action is null : "+postAction);       
        Form<Sysuser> sysuserForm = formFactory.form(Sysuser.class).bindFromRequest();  
        if (sysuserForm.hasErrors()) {
```

My routes :

```
POST    /sysusers/:id                  controllers.SysuserController.update(id:Long)
POST    /DelRoles/:id                  controllers.SysuserController.DeleteRoles(id:Long)
```

My model :

```
@Entity 
public class Sysuser extends BaseModel {

    @Constraints.Required
    public String username;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Role> roles;
```

Any idea please ?

Or may be there is another way to get manytomany fields values from bindFromRequest ?
Thank you so much